# Check whether image column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out whether an image column in table is null. I've been trying to use `CASE` but I always get an error.

Query:

```
SELECT  OutgoindDoc = CASE ReceivedData       
                        WHEN null THEN 'null'
                        ELSE CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),ReceivedData))) 
                      END
FROM    ib_IncomingData
```

And the error I'm getting:

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

What can I use to get the results I need?

Comment: Why are you converting it to `XML` to find out if it is `NULL`?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - What is he doing then? If the column is `NULL` then the result of the cast will be `NULL` anyway so why return NULL as a string?

Comment: @Martin Smith - I'm converting it to XML if it's not null.

Comment: @Gisli - Why not just cast it anyway without testing?

Comment: You answer is in your error message, you should have researched this simple clue! Questions showing such a lack of research normally get down votes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Because he wants the string `'null'` in that case. Why are you nitpicking? You're ignoring the spirit of the question entirely.

Comment: @webturner - I'm sorry if this offended you but sometimes it are the obvious things that elude us.  To Martin Smith - I was getting a different error earlier and I thought it was because I was trying to converting null. It was not the case so I'm back to square one. Thanks for the help

Comment: No offence, Just helping you get on the right track here without getting frustrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CASE <expression> WHEN <value> THEN` uses equality/equivalence comparison, but you need an `IS NULL` check because `NULL` is not a comparable quantity and — as the error indicates — images can't be "compared".

Fortunately, [there is another construct](http://allwrong.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/sql-when-case-null-fails/) — `CASE WHEN <test> THEN` — that brings the equality out into the user-provided parameters, allowing you to omit it:

```
SELECT  OutgoindDoc = CASE
                        WHEN ReceivedData IS NULL THEN
                           'null'
                        ELSE
                           CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),ReceivedData))) 
                      END
FROM    ib_IncomingData
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT  OutgoindDoc = CASE       
                        WHEN ReceivedData IS NULL THEN 'null'
                        ELSE CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),ReceivedData))) 
                      END
FROM    ib_IncomingData
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise version

```
SELECT  OutgoindDoc = 
         ISNULL(CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),ReceivedData))) ,'null')
FROM    ib_IncomingData
```

Although from the comments it seems you don't really need to do this anyway.